# Display online NSE (National Stock Exchange) data in php web application

Tags: php, widget

I want to display online NSE (National Stock Exchange) data in my php web application. Please help me how to do this.

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is or are you having problems starting all together?

Comment: Hi Ashok, I am also working on a similar project. Can you please answer finally what method you have implemented for your application ? If your application is live can you provide the URL. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google api .. they provide real time data for NSE.
but the catch is google finance api is available for java only it was not available for c# last time i checked.
Not sure about whether finance api are there for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Find out if NSX has a web service that exposes the stock charts. If so, this will likely be a REST or a SOAP endpoint that can be queried for specific stocks.

Create a PHP component that makes a request to that endpoint, and caches the results for a certain period of time (so that your site visitors don't have to wait for the roundtrip every time a page is loaded).

Answer (score 0):

NSE don't have any web service AFAIK, the only thing they export is previous day data. You might have to do some sort of data parsing on the NSE webpages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take historical data from NSE website, you can always do that.
for example, following is the url to retrieve nifty index data.

[http://www.nseindia.com/content/indices/histdata/S&P%20CNX%20NIFTY01-02-2010-04-02-2010.csv]
observe date pattern in the url, it is from 01 FEB 2010 to 04 FEB 2010.

change dates as you need, call the url from your server. It is csv format, so any language can process it.

Regards.

http://www.kakup.com